# Getting a pixel color from inside a game

Tags: java, pixel

I'm trying to get a pixel color while playing a game(exe) but I keep getting g,r,b  = 0, the code is working perfectly outside the game.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(3000);
PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point coord = pointer.getLocation();
Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY());
System.out.println("Red   = " + color.getRed());
System.out.println("Green = " + color.getGreen());
System.out.println("Blue  = " + color.getBlue());
```

So is it possible to get a pixel information from a game?

Comment: I can assure you that it can work, I did the same thing to create a cheat bot :) `robot.getPixelColor()` is what you need. I suggest to check if the coords returned from `MouseInfo` are correct (in my case, I used fixed coords and not mouse location)

Comment: @oneiros thanks for your comment, the following code: Color color = robot.getPixelColor(100,100); is giving me the same results. r,g,b = 0 while it shouldn't.

Comment: @ImriPersiado what @Oneiros meant is that you should check the return Coordinates returned by the `Point PointerInfo.getLocation()` - they are probably not correct. Why? Many games "hijack" the Pointer and hide it to display their own or block access to it as long as they are in focus. Try to print out the coordinates and most certainly you would get values like 0,0 - which don't represent the real pointer value, since it is not accessible

Comment: @ImriPersiado that's weird, it should work with fixed coordinates. Are you calling this procedure just once (at program launch)? In my case it was called in a loop. I share the code: http://pastebin.com/xB7YYxHT (I used it to cheat in FFX thunder plains haha: when it detects a white pixel in that position, it triggers a keypressed event)

Comment: @Oneiros nice I'm trying something similiar with a MMORPG game but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret I've tried it without the cursor, just getting the information with fixed coordinates and it's not working. I'll add that key presses and mouse clicks are working fine.

Comment: @Oneiros maybe it's possible to get the pixel information in another way?

Comment: @ImriPersiado I'm not aware of any other methods in Java. Have you tried in window mode? I don't think it would work if the game is running in fullscreen

Comment: @Oneiros it works in wondows mode! post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPixelColor()` seems to work only in window mode: open your game settings and disable fullscreen!